# Invoke method from java agent

Tags: java, javaagents

I try to create java agent. I want to invoke method in the running process, this is static method.

I tried get the class with

```
 class.forName(className);
```

But this give me ClassNotFoundException.
How can I get a class from the agent?

I understand that I need to add class-path, Their is an option to include the class-path of the  process that the agent "connected" to?

Thanks.

Comment: You need to make sure the class (or jar) is in the classpath of the application.

Comment: @DarshanMehta What I can do if I dont know the path of this classes on the system? But only know that com.dir.className ?